# sending Json as callback

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to Swift and I am trying to send my post result to another class 
this is my post function:

```
static func SetOrder(Json json : String , 
callback:@escaping (_ state:Int ,_ order : [Order])->Void){

let uri = ORDER + Auth(index: 1)
NetworkConnection.postData(Url: uri, Json: json) { (respone, state) in
    if state == 1 {
           callback( 1, [respone as! Order])
    } else {
        callback(0 , [respone as! Order] )
    } } }
```

and this is the class that I want to use my result:

```
Order.SetOrder(Json: orderJson as! String, callback: { (state , json) in
    if state == 1 {
        if self.order.payment_method == "something" {
            print("this is order")
            print(json)

            //===== if cashier on Net ====================
            var URlToPayment = getCheckoutUrl(OrderNumber: json.id 
              ,OrderKey:  json.order_key)
             GO TO PEYMEnt
            let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string:"\(URlToPayment)")
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
        } 
    }
})
```

Comment: if you want to send a json why are you sending "Order" object in callback?

Comment: As an aside, the indentation is all messed up. Read some style guides or basic best practices for formatting swift. Better formatted code is easier to reason about in my honest opinion. Allows for easier chunking of the program in your brain.

Comment: As you titled question as sending Json as callback, but in methods call back you are sending and object of type `Order`. A bit confusing, problem is not clear.